# Why can't I assign value to a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

Please see image below:

[image]

How can I modify the syntax so as to be able to assign specific values to specific cells in the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assign values in the class body, unless you write it in initialiser block or constructor. So write in the block as mentioned below or assign in constructor.

```
public class Maze{

    private int maze[][] = new int[5][5];

    //Changing the value using initializer block
    {
        maze[1][1] = 1;
    }

    //Changing the value using constructor
    public Maze(){
        maze[1][1]=5;
    }

    public int[][] getMaze() {
        return maze;
    }

    public void setMaze(int[][] maze) {
        this.maze= maze;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Maze maze = new Maze();
        int maze[][] = maze.getMaze();
        //Changing the value after creating object
        maze[1][2] = 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you modify the values later after the array was initialized?

Comment: You can modify in the same way in constructor, initialiser block or after you have created the object

Comment: Check the update answer for different options to change values

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to assign values is by writing a custom method with Maze class and using it in your main method. For ex:

```
private void updateMaze(int val, int i, int j) {
   maze[i][j] = val;
}
```

Depending on the use case, different access modifier can be used.